# How to fix "skipping line" error when reading a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

when I read my file:

```
for path in filepaths:
    df = pd.read_csv(r"{}".format(path), header=6, sep=",", engine="python", error_bad_lines=False)#, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    # drops the columns that won't be used
    df = df.drop(col_list, axis=1)
    # adds all the files data to list
    all_files.append(df)
```

I get the following error:

```
Skipping line 62: ',' expected after '"'
Skipping line 37: ',' expected after '"'
Skipping line 84: Expected 8 fields in line 84, saw 9
Skipping line 82: ',' expected after '"'
Skipping line 86: ',' expected after '"'
```

by using the following code that I saw someone suggest, I can print the lines that are causing the error:

```
def checkRow(path, N):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        print(f"This is the {N}th line.")
        return(next(itertools.islice(csv.reader(f), N, None)))
```

output:

```
This is the 62th line.
['56=', ' 56', '  9.3916', ' 0.1440', 'Propanedioic acid, propyl-', ' 21508', '000616-62-6', '50']
This is the 37th line.
['31=', ' 31', '  5.2522', ' 0.5319', '4-Heptanone (CAS) $$ GBL $$ Butyrone $$ Propyl ketone $$ Dipropyl ketone $$ Di-n-propyl ketone $$ Heptan-4-one $$ (n-C3H7)2CO $$ UN 2710 $$ 4-HEPTANON', ' 12512', '000123-19-3', '87']
This is the 84th line.
['78=', ' 78', ' 11.1865', ' 0.0182', 'Urea', '   300', '000057-13-6', '50']
```

but I can't detect the problem here.
I tried using the csv.QUOTE_NONE parameter that I saw someone suggest but that results in all the lines being skipped:

```
# opening all files in folders
for path in filepaths:
    df = pd.read_csv(r"{}".format(path), header=6, sep=",", engine="python", error_bad_lines=False), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    # drops the columns that won't be used
    df = df.drop(col_list, axis=1)
    # adds all the files data to list
    all_files.append(df)
```

error:

```
.....
Skipping line 55: Expected 8 fields in line 55, saw 9
Skipping line 57: Expected 8 fields in line 57, saw 9
Skipping line 59: Expected 8 fields in line 59, saw 10
Skipping line 60: Expected 8 fields in line 60, saw 9
Skipping line 62: Expected 8 fields in line 62, saw 10
Skipping line 63: Expected 8 fields in line 63, saw 10
Skipping line 67: Expected 8 fields in line 67, saw 9
Skipping line 69: Expected 8 fields in line 69, saw 11
.....
```

Comment: Could you show the actual lines 62, 37, 64, etc. rather than use a csv reader, that way we can see the actual line contents.

Comment: @JonathanCowling thanks for replying, I'm not sure where to find these lines because I am opening multiple files, so when the error says "skipping line 62" I'm not sure which file it is referring to.

Comment: Okay, any chance you could find a file with one of the errors, you could try printing the filename before printing any errors, or narrow down a file with errors by testing them in batches or one at a time (depending on how many you're working with). What I'm looking for in particular is to see if it's the CSV files themselves that contain errors, and if so what kind, once that is ruled out then it makes sense to look in more detail at the code itself. Based on the errors above, I think some CSV files don't have all 6 columns for the rows you've mentioned (but it would be best to confirm that).